# How to replace angular 2 constant variables in tfs build

Tags: angular, tfs

How to replace angular 2 constant variables (host) for different environments with TFS build? Are gulp tasks only solution or can we use token replacement extension?

Comment: As Julia said CLI Environment Option is the better way. You can use token replace task to replace value, such as https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=qetza.replacetokens

Answer (score 0):

If you are using angular-cli you can configure env variables in environments folder.

```
export const environment = {
 production: true,
 domain: 'xxxx'
};
```

after that import it in component

```
import {environment} from '../environments/environment';

@Component({...})
export class MyCpm {

  constructor() {
   console.log(environment.domain);
  }
 }
```

Comment: did you try this with tfs build and how does tfs differentiate between production: true and production: false? Any example?

Comment: u have a file per each enviroment.ts envoroment.prod.ts and angular-cli will pick the correct one

Comment: and if you are not using angular-cli but visual studio?

Comment: angular-cli is a recommended way for angular projects.

Answer (score 0):

You can use token replacement extension, such as [# Replace Tokens](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=qetza.replacetokens).

1. Add a variable to build/release definition (e.g. myVar: hello)
2. Change your code, for example: export const name=’{myVar}’. (Note: you can store the value in a json file (value is {myVar}).
3. Add Replace Tokens step/task
4. Specify Target files (e.g. ***.ts ***.json)

Comment: yeah, but then you have export const name = '{myVar}' in localhost environment, which means if it is host variable for example... it fails :)

Comment: @AmelSalibasic Not clear what you mean. You also could replace the value with your own logical through PowerShell, for example simulate angular-cli environment logical.

Comment: when you run application on localhost, you obviously need value instead of generic {myVar}, so if your file settings.ts has {myVar} how are you going to read that value when you start app localy?

Comment: @AmelSalibasic You need to change {myVar} to the actual value if running application on localhost. The better way is to do it with the PowerShell script (like angular-cli)